# How to split counts from the same column in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table as the below:

```
employeeID deparment  gender
1          IT         male
2          IT         female
3          RRHH       male
```

I need a query that shows percentage of males and women by departament. Something like that:

```
Deparment Gender  Percentage
IT        males   35%
IT        females 65%
RRH       males   45%
and so on
```

Any help?

Comment: Read about aggregate queries, you're gonna need `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 0):

A friend help me to find the solution:

```
select gender,  count (gender),  dep_name,  
count (gender) / SUM (count(gender)) OVER (PARTITION BY dep_name)
from employee
group by gender, dep_name
order by dep_name
```